# Positioning objects tkinter

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I'm trying to create an easy interface in python with tkinter, that's what I need:
[image: what I need]

I tried whit this code:

```
from tkinter import *


class Fullscreen:
    def __init__(self):
        self.window = Tk()
        self.window.attributes('-fullscreen', True)
        self.fullScreenState = False
        self.window.bind("<F11>", self.toggleFullScreen)
        self.window.bind("<Escape>", self.quitFullScreen)
        left = Label(self.window, text="hello ovest").grid(sticky=W+N)
        right = Label(self.window, text="hello est").grid(sticky=E+N)
        bottom = Label(self.window, text="hello bottom").grid(sticky=S)

        self.window.mainloop()

    def toggleFullScreen(self, event):
        self.fullScreenState = not self.fullScreenState
        self.window.attributes("-fullscreen", self.fullScreenState)

    def quitFullScreen(self, event):
        self.fullScreenState = False
       self.window.attributes("-fullscreen", self.fullScreenState)


app = Fullscreen()
```

And that's what I'm obtaining:
[image: what I obtain]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the rows and columns to build the grid, for example:

```
Label(self.window, text="Left").grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nws")
Label(self.window, text="Right").grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="nse")
Label(self.window, text="Bottom").grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky="wes")
```

You also need to tell the geometry manager how to distribute the additional space:

```
self.window.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
self.window.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
self.window.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
```

See http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/grid.htm for more information on how the grid geometry manager works.

Answer (score 0):

`pack` is the simplest choice for this type of layout.

```
left = Label(self.window, text="hello ovest")
right = Label(self.window, text="hello est")
bottom = Label(self.window, text="hello bottom")

bottom.pack(side="bottom", fill="x")
left.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=True)
right.pack(side="right", fill="both", expand=True)
```